# Jekyll show only specific tag on page

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm using jekyll, and I'm trying to have a page ( /play) show only posts tagged Play, and the same with Work (/work). How can I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by iterating through the site's tags and indexing into the array with the tag name, similar to the following:

```
{% for post in site.tags.Play %}
<h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
<time>{{ post.date }}</time>
{% endfor %}
```

It's a bit confusing because it seems like `site.tags` returns a collection of tags, but it actually contains the full posts, indexed by tag.

[See `site.tags.TAG` in the Jekyll Variables page](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/).

Answer (score 2):

[@briantist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3905079/briantist) is right, you have to dig in the site.tags collection.

In order get a more maintainable code, you can use [Jekyll includes](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#includes).

A tag page (eg: ruby.html) is just calling an include passing it the ruby tagName :

```
---
layout: page
title: Ruby
---

{% include tagPagesLoop.html tagName='ruby' %}
```

**_includes/tagPagesLoop.html**

```
<h2>All {{ include.tagName }} posts</h2>

{% for post in site.tags[include.tagName] %}
<h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
other stuff here
{% endfor %}
```

All changes made in this include is present in all pages that use it.